Restricting color options in Django admin form based on previously selected colors
I have two models, Product and Color, connected via ManyToManyFields. I want to restrict the color options available when editing a product in the Django admin interface.
Models:
class Color(models.Model):  
   coid = ShortUUIDField(length=10, max_length=100, prefix="col", alphabet="abcdefgh")  
   name = models.CharField(max_length=20)  
   code = ColorField(default='#FF0000')  
   product_varients = models.ManyToManyField('Product', related_name='color_variants', blank=True)  
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to=color_directory_path, default="product.jpg")  
  
class Product(models.Model):  
   pid = ShortUUIDField(length=10, max_length=100, prefix="prd", alphabet="abcdef")  
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Apple")  
   color = models.ManyToManyField(Color, blank=True)  
   price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=1.99)

Goal:
When creating or editing a product, I want to restrict the colors in the color field to those that have been previously selected in the color field of the same product. In other words, I want the color field to show only colors associated with the product’s color, not all colors available in the database.
What I Need:

I want the color field in the Product admin form to display only the colors that are linked to the color of that product.
If no color is set, I want the color field to be empty or show no options.

Current Behavior:
When I click on the color field in the Product admin form, it redirects me to the Color model, and then if I click on the product_varients field, it reopens the Product model, creating a chain system. I want to show only the colors associated with the product’s color.

Have you shared your forms.py file?
